# Keep playlist always in shuffle

Tags: music-player

I am using the default android music player and I tend to always play playlists in shuffle mode. I find it unintuitive though that I cannot set a playlist to play in shuffle by default, I need to manually select shuffle each time. Is there a setting that I have overlooked or otherwise how can I do this? Happy to use another music player but I have tried many of the popular ones and they appear to have the same issue.

Comment: Going by the name, this may work https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HIGStudio.REALShufflePlayer

Comment: Tried this out but it doesn't have anything different to the default music player. Yes it is random but you still can't set it per playlist. Kept crashing on me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution to this, will leave this in case someone has a better one. Basically by adding the full music widget to the homepage you can easily toggle the global shuffle setting and play a playlist from the same place. This doesn't let you set it per playlist but since you don't need to keep pressing shuffle each time you play it works similarly. Closest I have found so far.